# Prototype library component for the select box options

Tags: select, combobox, components, prototypejs

An UI question...

There are two select boxes between which there are two buttons "<<" and ">>". When you hit the "<<" button the selected items from the select item on the right moves to the left and similarly from left to right ">>". I am not sure what this kind of set up is called in terms of or jargon or terminology ;)

I wanted to know if there is a prototype component like this existing already? or an optimized way of doing this with Prototype library?

Thanks, J

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed terminology of your required UI problem, so far to my knowledge. Still you may call it as "Moving selected Items from one Listbox to another".

For reference, you can see [this example](http://personal-universe.net/qformgen/), which is built using plain JavaScript.

Also I am pretty sure that there is some way to build this type of functionality using **Prototype** & **Scriptaculous** libraries, along with the effects. You will require the "Sortables" object, most probably.

Hope it helps.